# Edit error message content 'This is a required field'

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm looking to change the error messages display. I want replace with custom content of default error message i.e. 'This is a required field'.

Example;

Configurable Product: It returns the error message 'This is a required field' if add-to-cart button is clicked without an required attribute selected. I'd like it to return my custom message for all fields like ''Please select a {attribute_label}'. This way it will show, 'Please select a size' or 'Please select a color'.

Same for all fields like email and phone etc.

Please help me to understand if these error messages are called from a translation/language file or if each field has its own error message associated with itself.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't appear to be "proper Magento" way to do this (it would be nice if this message was configurable in the Admin area!), but I figured out one way to get this working with Swatches for Size and Color with a Theme file override.

Magento 2 form validation is built on the [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin, which is actually pretty easy to set custom validation messages with, but it can be more difficult depending on which Magento component you are working with.

To change the validation messages for Configurable product "Swatch" attributes, I had to override the JS file that dynamically builds the Swatch elements:

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

into my theme:

```
app/design/frontend/YourCompany/yourtheme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Then I modified the `_RenderFormInput()` method which outputs the swatch `<input>` elements to have the `data-msg-required` attribute, like so:

```
_RenderFormInput: function (config) {
        var msgTxt = $.mage.__("Please select");
        return '<input class="' + this.options.classes.attributeInput + ' super-attribute-select" ' +
            'name="super_attribute[' + config.id + ']" ' +
            'type="text" ' +
            'value="" ' +
            'data-selector="super_attribute[' + config.id + ']" ' +
            'data-validate="{required:true}" ' +
            // THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
            'data-msg-required="' + msgTxt + ' ' + config.label + '" ' +
            'aria-required="true" ' +
            'aria-invalid="true" ' +
            'style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute; left:-1000px">';
    },
```

`config.label` is the human readable, translated attribute name.

The jQuery Validation plugin parses this and uses it as the validation error message. The `required` part of the `data-msg-required` attribute name reflects the `required` validator. If the `minlength` rule were being used, the `data-msg-minlength` attribute would customize that error message, etc. ([Docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-error-messages))

If you look up how to customize the validation messages for the jQuery Validation plugin you'll find other methods as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777634/jquery-validation-plugin-custom-message

Answer (score 1):

You need to add mix-in js to make code follow standard of Magento
Create a file in module or theme, my case is in theme:
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js
add this code to mix-in file

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
'use strict';

return function (SwatchRenderer) {
    $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', $['mage']['SwatchRenderer'], {
        _RenderFormInput: function (config) {
            var msgTxt = $.mage.__("Please select an option before adding to basket");
            return '<input class="' + this.options.classes.attributeInput + ' super-attribute-select" ' +
                'name="super_attribute[' + config.id + ']" ' +
                'type="text" ' +
                'value="" ' +
                'data-selector="super_attribute[' + config.id + ']" ' +
                'data-validate="{required:true}" ' +
                'data-msg-required="' + msgTxt + '" ' +
                'aria-required="true" ' +
                'aria-invalid="true" ' +
                'style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute; left:-1000px">';
        }
    });
    return $['mage']['SwatchRenderer'];
};});
```

In module or theme create this file requirejs-config.js:
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js
and add this code:

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
        }
    }
}};
```

Now you did mixin for this function